# myArray.join(....).split(...) print

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

I have

```
var myArray = ["word", "are", "tame"];
var result = myArray.join('s').split('a');
```

1)computed: "wordsarestame"

2)computed: "words", "rest", "me"

My question is for the first computed,

computed: "wordsarestame"

why don't you add a 's' at the end of me? since it's .`join('s')` on whole myArray

Comment: Because `join` fills *between* elements and since there is no element after `'tame'` no s is added

Comment: ah ok I see .  fill blank space bla bla bla bla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.join` joins the elements of the array - it means it puts a glue element **between** each two array elements in succession. That's why you don't have it neither at the beginning of joined string, nor at the end of it.

Answer (score 2):

You're joining 3 things, so you get 2 `s` in between. It's the same as doing:

```
var joined = "word" + "s" + "are" + "s" + "tame"
```

Answer (score 1):

Join combines the array into a string, and uses the provided string as the glue that holds them together. You don't need to glue anything at the end of the last string, so no more glue is applied:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arr.join('x'));
```

You could use `map()` to get your desired result:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arr.map(str => str + 'x').join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.join()
```

[manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=example)

> The join() method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like
>   object) into a string.

It glue each element of array elements. If you want to add a after theme, add another '' element of the array, then ues join().

```js
var myArray = ["word", "are", "tame"];
myArray.push('');
console.log(myArray.join('s'));
```